# sql developer mysql connection to remote db using wrong host

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am on a windows 7 machine running sql developer and I'm trying to connect to a mysql db on a different host. I installed the mysql jdbc connector so that a MySql tab shows up when I create a new db connection. MySql is up and running on the remote machine and I can access it locally. I can also access it remotely via a php web connection. My difficulty is confined to accessing it via sql developer on my local machine.
My specific problem is that it seems to be using my local hostname (I substituted mymachine.domain for discussion purposes) rather than the hostname I specified in the connection. When I try to connect I get the following:

Access denied for user 'epdmadusr'@'mymachine.domain' (using password: YES) Vendor code 1045

Why is it using 'mymachine.domain' for the hostname instead of the hostname I specified in the connection?